# Falha ao criar diretorio?

Tags: android, android-studio, syntax-error

```
  error: failed to create directory '\\?\D:\APLICATIVOS ANDROID\Aplicativos\Aplicativo VideoApp Download\VideoApp\VideoApp\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\com\pixelstock\VideoAppTest'.
```

Estou tentando gerar uma build debug
e está aparecendo esse erro

Estou tentando fazer isso em outra máquina, já dei permissão de administrador e mesmo assim o erro persiste

Alguma sugestão?
Windows 10

Comment: Qual o nome do pacote do seu app? É a primeira vez que acontece? Se criar outro projeto e buildar vai de boa?

Comment: sim sim vai de boa, qualquer outra build vai tranquilo